# How to plot a filled.contour plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have some data and I have tried a `filled.contour` plot which seems nice. However, the legend is hard to control, so I am thinking to use `ggplo2`. But I have no clue how to plot a `filled.contour` using `ggplot2`.

The data contains 840 rows (which stand for the dates), and 12 columns (which stand for 12 time scales). Here is an example

```
set.seed(66)
Mydata <- sample(x=(-3:3),size = 840*12,replace = T)
Mydata <- matrix(data=Mydata,nrow=840,ncol=12)
Dates <- seq(from=1948+1/24, to= 2018,by=1/12)
data.breaks <- c(-3.5,-2.5,-1.5,0,1.5,2.5,3.5)
filled.contour(Dates,seq(1:12),Mydata,col=cols(11),xlab="",ylab="time-scale",levels=data.breaks)
```

[image]

As we can see, the legend intervals are not what I want. I want to show `-3.5,-2.5,-1.5,0,1.5,2.5,3.5`on the legend and I believe it is much easier to do this with `ggplot2`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ggplot2` alternative to `filled.contour` is `stat_contour`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(66)
Mydata <- sample(x=(-3:3),size = 840*12,replace = T)
Mydata <- matrix(data=Mydata,nrow=840,ncol=12)
Dates <- seq(from=1948+1/24, to= 2018,by=1/12)
data.breaks <- c(-3.5,-2.5,-1.5,0,1.5,2.5,3.5)
rownames(Mydata) <- Dates

d <- melt(Mydata)
colfunc = colorRampPalette(c("brown", "red", "yellow", "white"))
ggplot(d, aes(Var1, Var2, z=value, fill = value)) +
     stat_contour(geom="polygon", aes(fill=..level..)) +
     scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colfunc(7), breaks=data.breaks, limits=c(-4,4),
                          values=scales::rescale(data.breaks))+
     theme_bw() + 
     scale_x_continuous(name="", breaks=seq(1950,2010,20), expand=c(0,0)) + 
     scale_y_continuous(name="time-scale", expand=c(0,0))+
     guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 2, barheight = 15))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But I wonder how to get the legend breaks that I want? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the figure plotted by `ggplot2` is quite different from that plotted by `filled.contour`, could you fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YangYang In what sense is "quite different" ? I replicated it using `filled.contour` but I found only minor differences. Please, give me more details.

Comment: Sorry for the vague expression. What I mean is that from the figure in my post, we can see obvious red and yellow bands (for example, we can see a strong red band around 1970 ). However, with `ggplot2`, we cannot see clearly where the band is. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YangYang You generated the `Mydata` matrix using the `sample` function, hence your data are completely random. They cannot have the pattern shown in your figure. I suggest to carefully check your original dataset. If possibile, share the dataset pasting the output of `dput(Mydata)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, and it is the data that I need to check. Thanks a lot.